# "Apache is functioning normally" on server wildcard subdomains

Tags: apache, centos, wildcard-subdomain

I have a website that use wildcard-subdomain to change languages. I work fine in localhost.

When I upload to server, the default pages work fine but when I switch to English like this

> **nghiemthu.net** to **en.nghiemthu.net**

only appear the message:

> Apache is functioning normally

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have somewhere in `/etc/httpd/` a file with `ServerName nghiemthu.net` (probably inside a `<VirtualHost *:80>`).

You need to declare the other domains to serve with [`ServerAlias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias).

Here, it seems (you didn't post your configuration so I'm guessing) the request doesn't match any virtual host and goes to the default one (serving the default html file).

See also [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) and [name-based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already activated your SSL certification, then activate it.
If you **have** already activated your SSL certification, then remove it.